# How to send mailchimp templates with mandrill?

Tags: node.js, email, mailchimp

How to send mailchimp templates with mandrill?

i have build a template in Mailchimp and send to mandrill.
[image]

when I called this API, it sent a plain email without the template. how to send with the template?

```
const response = await mailchimp.messages.send({
            template_name:"Test",
            message: {
                from_email: "noreply@mydomain.com",
                subject: "Hello world",
                text: "Welcome to Mailchimp Transactional!",
                to: [{
                    email: "myname@gmail.com",
                    type: "to"
                }]
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am trying to send a message using messages/send-template it says "No template found". Can you help

Comment: How you sent it to mandrill. I'm cannot find send to mandrill?

Answer (score 1):

you must use .messages.sendTemplate not .messages.send

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out, you have to add a empty content field

```
const response = await mailchimp.messages.send({
            template_name:"Test",
            template_content: [],<--------ADD THIS
            message: {
                from_email: "noreply@mydomain.com",
                subject: "Hello world",
                text: "Welcome to Mailchimp Transactional!",
                to: [{
                    email: "myname@gmail.com",
                    type: "to"
                }]
            }
        });
```